# What is the best way to fetch users list from XMPP roaster?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I integrated XMPP chat server in my iOS application. From DidReceiveIQ, It gives the users list after connection to XMPP server.But If I add any new user to roaster , DidReceiveIQ gives only newly added user and not the compete list. So, my question here is what will be the best way to fetch users list from roaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check iPhoneXMPP example application bundled with [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework): when you plug in `XMPPRoster` module with `XMPPRosterMemoryStorage` or `XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage` - it will automatically sync users with selected storage, including future addition and deletion, and you can use that storage as datasource for your `UITableView`, etc.